# TextField font style missing when it holding Japanese character

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Passing the String to a view**

```
// Case 1: English alphabet is no problem
test(deck: "ABCDE")

// Case 2: Font style is missing
test(deck: "アイウエオ")

// Case 3: Font style is missing
test(deck: "ABCアイウエオDE")
```

> Result: case1  [image]
>
> Result: case2 [image]
>
> Result: case3 [image]

**Destination view: Store the string value in a text field**

```
struct test: View {
    @State var deck : String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            TextField("deck name", text: $deck)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(1)
        }

        
    }
}
```

As you can see, the font style not working properly when the text field holding Japanese Characters.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is bugged with the latest version of xCode and iOS. The problem only occurs when using a `TextField`. If you use a normal `Text` it works fine.

If I found a way to fix this I'll let you know. Till then **you can't use a `TextField` with this set of characters.**