# SwiftUI TextField font size not working with unicode

Tags: unicode, ios13, xcode11, swiftui

TextField font size is only working with English alphabets and not unicode like Chinese and Korean.

I have sample code below and the result photo.
Texts in the result photo has all the same font size.
But it works in Text view and TextField with **placeholder** and not for TextField writing texts.

Anyone has an idea?

[image: result]

```swift
struct TextFieldUnicode: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var placeholderText: String = "(TextField view) placeholder : 你好, 안녕, hello"
    @State var realText: String = "(TextField view) writing text : 你好, 안녕, hello"
    let textViewText = "(Text view) text : 你好, 안녕, hello"

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text(textViewText)
                .font(.custom("SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 12))
            TextField(placeholderText, text: $text) // empty text, only place holder
                .font(.custom("SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 12))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            TextField(placeholderText, text: $realText) // writing text
                .font(.custom("SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 12))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Known issue. [Here is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017465/textfield-font-style-missing-when-it-holding-japanese-character)